# How to get redirect Log from TestServerFixture to ITestOutputHelper in .net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

I currently have my tests failing in the build machine in VSTS, and it's really hard to know what happened. I have a lot of logs generated by the API which could be really helpful.

My purpose is to have ALL the log generated in my API redirected to the OutputTestHelper.

Using Xunit, I have a TestServerFixture:

```
 public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public TestServer Server { get; }
        public HttpClient Client { get; }
        public T GetService<T>() => (T)Server.Host.Services.GetService(typeof(T));

        public TestServerFixture()
        {
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {

                    logging.AddXunit(output); //How Can I get ITestOuputHelper?
                });

            Server = new TestServer(builder);
            Client = Server.CreateClient();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Server.Dispose();
            Client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Reading this:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/d9b34d1c36fde204bd736d09b89b86451bd82e95/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Testing/XunitLoggerFactoryExtensions.cs
- [.net core 2.0 ConfigureLogging xunit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169169/net-core-2-0-configurelogging-xunit-test/46172875#46172875)

I have an extension allowing me to add Xunit ITestOutputHelper to the logger (**AddXunit()**) which need *ITestOutputHelper*  as parameter.

The things is, I dont find a way to get it in TestServerFixture. I tried:

- maybe there is some Injection available in the constructore of TestServerFixture which could instance ITestOutputHelper ? `public TestServerFixture(ITestOutputHelper output)` => FAILED
- maybe there a way to resolve from IloggingBuilder.Services theITestOutputHelper (like `loggingBuilder.Services.Resolve<ITestOutputHelper>()`) => FAILED
- maybe I can get it from *Configure* method in TestStartup (like `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ITestOutputHelper output)`) => FAILED

Do you know a way to Configure the TestServerFixture to redirect ALL log to OutpuTestHelper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution. As it's not possible to access to ITestOutpuHelper from Injection, I have no other way that to create a new TestServerFixture to each Test class.

What I have before:

```
public class Users_Tests
{
    [...]
    public Users_Tests(
        TestServerFixture server
        ITestOutputHelper output
    )
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

What I have now:

```
public class Users_Tests
{
    [...]
    public Users_Tests(
        ITestOutputHelper output
    )
    {
        TestServerFixture = new TestServerFixture(output);    
        [...]
    }
}
```

So my TestServiceFixture now is:

```
public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable
{
    public TestServer Server { get; }
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    public T GetService<T>() => (T)Server.Host.Services.GetService(typeof(T));

    public TestServerFixture(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddXunit(output);
            });

        Server = new TestServer(builder);
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Server.Dispose();
        Client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So now all logs are redirected to Output which helped me to understand where the error came from!

Comment: Yup that does the trick. Simply add IHttpClientFactory to constructor of your XUnit test and it will be injected.

Comment: Much simpler than https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/214 !

Comment: This workaround unfortunately doesn't work if you want a class fixture or collection fixture (which you possibly want in you scenario)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your DI (including `ILoggerFactory`) already configured on your fixture with a logger provider implementation which writes to xUnit output, then you should be able to just request `ILogger<whatever>` from the service provider on your fixture (using the `GetService<T>` method you show us in there).

The Microsoft's logger DI integration registers the service `ILogger<>` to provide a logger from the LoggerFactory (for which you need to register a provider, which is what you are doing with the `AddXunit` extension on your `ConfigureLogging` call)

Comment: Thanks for your help. From what I understood, the only way to resolve a Service is to build your webhostbuilder, in ConfigureLogging the hostingContext is not build so you can not resolve the service, so I had to think out the box and find a new way to the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not have a rigid requirement to procure logs via `ITestOutputHelper`, you can try out using the `IMessageSink` abstraction in xUnit, for logging inside TestFixtures.

```cs
public class SutTests : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture>
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output; // for logging inside test classes
    private readonly TestServerFixture  _fixture;

    public SutTests(TestServerFixture fixture, ITestOutputHelper output) {
        _fixture = fixture
        _output = output;
    }
    ...
}

public class TestServerFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly IMessageSink _sink; // for logging inside TestFixtures
    public TestServerFixture(IMessageSink sink) {
        _sink = sink;
        _sink.OnMessage(new DiagnosticMessage("Test Server Fixture Created."));
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync() {
        // initialize stuffs..
        _sink.OnMessage(new DiagnosticMessage("Fixture initialized."));
    }
    ...
}
```

**Notes**:

- You would need to [enable Diagnostic Messages](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#diagnosticMessages) in Xunit Configuration file.
- You would need XUnit version `2.4.1` or higher.