# Getting logger out in while doing unit test using xunit and .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am trying to get output from the logger when doing running my unit test in the output window but nothing shows. I am using ILoggingFactory in the test class. I am expecting to see all my log from the test class and the actual implementation class i.e. JobQueueManager.

Test.cs

```
public class ScheduledJobDatesTest :IClassFixture<ScheduleJobTestFixture>
    {
        private ScheduleJobTestFixture ScheduleJobFixtureHelper { get; }

        Mock<IDbConnection> mockJobQueueManager = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        ILoggerFactory logger = new LoggerFactory();

        public ScheduledJobDatesTest(ScheduleJobTestFixture scheduleJobFixture)
        {
            ScheduleJobFixtureHelper = scheduleJobFixture;

            mockJobQueueManager.SetReturnsDefault(new SqlConnection());
            logger = LoggerFactory.Create(a => a.AddConsole());
            logger.CreateLogger("Executing Test");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ValidScheduledJobDateForNextWeeklyAppointment()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Testing");
            logger.CreateLogger("Test").LogInformation("Test Information");
            //Arrange
            JobQueueManager jobQueueManager = new JobQueueManager(mockJobQueueManager.Object, logger.CreateLogger<JobQueueManager>());
            var scheduledJob = ScheduleJobFixtureHelper.GetMockedScheduledJob(JobType.Week);
            //Act
            bool isTrue = jobQueueManager.IsScheduledJobDateValidForJobType(scheduledJob.JobDate);
            //Assert
            Assert.True(isTrue);
        }
```

}

JobQueueManager.cs

```
public class JobQueueManager : IJobQueueManager
    {
        public IDbConnection DBConnection { get; }
        public ILogger<JobQueueManager> Logger { get; }

        public JobQueueManager(IDbConnection dbConnection, ILogger<JobQueueManager> logger)
        {
            DBConnection = dbConnection;
            Logger = logger;
            Logger.LogInformation("Initialized Job Queue Manager");
        }

    public bool IsScheduledJobDateValidForJobType(DateTime ScheduledJobDate)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("Verifying  unit test");
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var nextJobDate = ScheduledJobDate;
            if (nextJobDate > currentDate)
            {
                var appointmentsDaysDifference = Math.Ceiling((nextJobDate - currentDate).TotalDays);
                if(appointmentsDaysDifference == 1)
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of xUnit are you using?

> If you used xUnit.net 1.x, you may have previously been writing output
>   to Console, Debug, or Trace. When xUnit.net v2 shipped with
>   parallelization turned on by default, this output capture mechanism
>   was no longer appropriate; it is impossible to know which of the many
>   tests that could be running in parallel were responsible for writing
>   to those shared resources. Users who are porting code from v1.x to
>   v2.x should use one of the two new methods instead.

[Source](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output)

There seems to be a number of ways to solve this, if it were me I'd look into implementing a [custom provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46172875/2975810).

Comment: This is an xUnit issue, and can be solved really easily as per the custom provider link. I wouldn't bring in another dependency to solve this problem.